# How can I reverse a Stack from a Linked List?

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, reverse

I am working on a project using Stacks in Linked Lists. I have to "Implement a stack including a tester. Methods include push, pop, isEmpty, and reverse." I'm working on my reverse method that is meant to reverse a stack. However, for this method, I'm only allowed to "use the following data type as a new variable: int, stack." In this method, I used my LinkedList project for the reverse method but in this case, I'm not allowed to. Does someone know how I would reverse a stack? My code is down below. The first code segment is for my LinkedList and the second code segment is for my Stack project.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class LinkedListOfInts {
    Node head;
    Node tail;

    private class Node {
        int value;
        Node nextNode;

        public Node(int value, Node nextNode) {
            this.value = value;
            this.nextNode = nextNode;
        }

    }

    public LinkedListOfInts(int N, int low, int high) {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            this.addToFront(random.nextInt(high - low) + low);
    }

    public void addToFront(int x) {
        head = new Node(x, head);
        if (tail == null)
            tail = head;
    }

    public int deleteFromFront() {
        int headValue = -1;
        if (head == null)
            return headValue;
        else {
            if (head == tail) {
                head = null;
                tail = null;
            } else {
                headValue = head.value;
                head = head.nextNode;
            }
        }
        return headValue;
    }

    public LinkedListOfInts reverse() {
        Node previous = null;
        Node current = head;
        Node next;
        while (current != null) {
            next = current.nextNode;
            current.nextNode = previous;
            previous = current;
            current = next;
        }
        head = previous;
        return this;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = "";
        for (Node ptr = head; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.nextNode) {
            if (!result.isEmpty()) {
                result += ", ";
            }
            result += ptr.value;
        }
        return "[" + result + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedListOfInts list = new LinkedListOfInts(5, 1, 10);
        System.out.println("Original List" + list.toString());
        list.addToFront(1);
        System.out.println("List After Adding One: " + list.toString());
        list.addToFront(2);
        System.out.println("List After Adding Two: " + list.toString());
        list.addToFront(3);
        System.out.println("List After Adding Three: " + list.toString());
        list.deleteFromFront();
        System.out.println("List After Deleting Item from the Front: " + list.toString());
        list.reverse();
        System.out.println("Reversed List: " + list.toString());

    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stack {
    LinkedListOfInts list = new LinkedListOfInts(5, 1, 10);

    public void push(int item) {
        list.addToFront(item);
    }

    public int pop() {
        return list.deleteFromFront();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        while (list.head != null) {
            list.head = null;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void reverse() {
        Stack tmpB = new Stack();
        while (!this.isEmpty()) {
            tmpB.push(this.pop());
        }
        Stack tmpC = new Stack();
        while (!tmpB.isEmpty()) {
            tmpC.push(tmpB.pop());
        }
        while (!tmpC.isEmpty()) {
            this.push(tmpC.pop());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Stack: " + list + "";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Stack stack = new Stack();
        boolean done = false;
        while (!done) {
            System.out.println("1. Push");
            System.out.println("2. Pop");
            System.out.println("3. Empty");
            System.out.println("4. Reverse");
            System.out.println("5. toString");
            switch (input.nextInt()) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Add an Item to the Front of the Stack");
                stack.push(input.nextInt());
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Delete an Item at the Front of the Stack");
                System.out.println(stack.pop());
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Empty a Stack");
                System.out.println(stack.isEmpty());
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Reverse the List");
                stack.reverse();
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("toString");
                System.out.println(stack.toString());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Reversing a stack containing one element is trvial, just do nothing. Now using only push and pop, how might you reverse a stack that contains exactly 2 elements?

Comment: your program works "nice" (except the "done" part maybe;)! what's the problem?

Comment: @xerx593 the problem is I'm not supposed to use "list.reverse();" I'm instead supposed to write out the code but I'm not sure how. I understand the logic of what I must do but I don't know how to even begin doing the reverse of a stack.

Comment: i think the(n) task here is: to push all into a new (tmp) stack, popping it back into `this` (list).

Comment: We’ll that I figured but how would I write the code. Would I write something like Stack tmp = list.head; ?

Comment: You evidently used an answer to update your question. That is not-done.

Comment: I updated the question with the answer to show that if you run it it won’t work.

Answer (score 1):

Solution description using only Stack operations (without code - that’s for you to write, which is the point of the exercise):

To create a new stack in reverse order, pop-push every element from old to new.

To reverse a stack, you need to empty it, then pop-push from a stack in same order.

So, if you want to reverse stack A, create 2 new stacks B and C. Pop-push from A->B, then B->C, then C->A.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after clarifying& fixing methods:

```
// easiest method to "empty the stack":
public void clear() {
   this.list  = new LinkedListOfInts();
}

//method identifies, whether there are elements in the stack:
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return list.head == null;
}
```

..and after fixing:

```
public int deleteFromFront() {
    int headValue = -1;
    if (head == null)
        return headValue;
    else { //! move headValue(return value) assignment here, otherwise it returns -1 on 1-element lists.
        headValue = head.value;
        if (head == tail) {
            head = null;
            tail = null;
        } else {
            head = head.nextNode;
        }
    }
    return headValue;
}
```

we can finally trick like:

```
public void reverse() {
    Stack tmp = new Stack();
    while (!this.isEmpty()) {
        tmp.push(this.pop());
    }
    this.list = tmp.list; // ;(;(
}
```

deliver/enjoy, after:

```
...
  case 3:
     System.out.println("Empty a Stack");
     stack.clear();
     System.out.println("Stack cleared!");
     break;
...
  case 6:
     System.out.println("bye!");
     done = true;
     break;
```

---

And as proposed by Bohemian the "pure stack" solution:

```
public void reverseStackOnly() { //works!+1^^
    Stack tmpB = new Stack();
    while (!this.isEmpty()) {
        tmpB.push(this.pop());
    }
    Stack tmpC = new Stack();
    while (!tmpB.isEmpty()) {
        tmpC.push(tmpB.pop());
    }
    while (!tmpC.isEmpty()) {
        this.push(tmpC.pop());
    }
}
```

Comment: When I reverse the stack it's empty

Comment: you have to rename the `isEmpty()` method.... (sorry! ..please read&apply answer detailed and carefully)

Comment: Even after Implementing the solution from Bohemian, the reverse method does not work. I have corrected my code above. The LinkedListOfInts program uses a constructor that generates a list of random integers between a range. I have referenced that constructor in the Stack program. When I try to reverse the Stack it's Empty. There are no values inside the stack.

Comment: a method called "isBlahBlah" should *not* do anything!!! ..but only **check** (for) "BlahBlah"!! (DETAILED! & carefully!)

Comment: I don't know if you realize it or care but this OP is using multiple accounts to get other people to do all his homework for him, including writing all his code.

Comment: I’m not trying to get the answers. I’m trying to get help with these methods. I want help in understanding why my code does not work and a solution that explains why does it work compared to why my code does not work. Hints aren’t going to be helping me out. I came to StackOverflow to get help as a last minute resort when I already tried changing my code a million times. I understand the logic behind the code but actually applying it to code is where I struggle.